# Joi validator extension which has a return value in setup() does not call validate()

Tags: node.js, joi, hapi

I have created an extension which implements both `setup()` and `validate()`. I expect both methods to be called, which they are. *But* if my `setup()` method returns a value, `validate()` is skipped completely and never called.

I would like to be able to have my `setup()` return a value and still be able to to validation in `validate()`.

```js
const WebhookUrlExtension = (joi) => joi.extend({
  base: joi.string(),
  name: 'string',
  rules: [
    {
      name: 'webhookUrl',
      validate (params, value, state, options) {
        console.log('VALIDATE') // not firing :( 
        return value;
      },
      params: {
        options: joi.object({
          scheme: joi.array().items(joi.string()).optional()
        })
      },
      setup (params) {
        console.log('SETUP') // this gets executed fine
        const regex = /^.+:\/\/.+/;
        const uriOpts = {
          scheme: Hoek.reach(params, 'options.scheme', { default: ['https'] })
        };
        return Joi.string().uri(uriOpts).regex(regex);  // if I remove this return statement, validate does run
      }
    }
  ]
});
```